# Last step in a simple proof:

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification

I've been writing a little algorithm, and I find it fun (and hopefully beneficial) to write the mathematical proofs that justify the algorithm's function.

Along those lines, I've written the following proof. However, my last statement is just intuition, and I'd like to convince myself of it:

> For any $n$, if $n= 2^x5^y$, then $1/n$ produces a terminating decimal
> number.
>
> Proof:
>
> Assume that n is of the form (2^x)(5^y). Choose $d = \max\{x, y\}$
>
> $\implies$ Then $10^d/n = (2^d)(5^d)/(2^x)(5^y)$
>
> $\implies$ Without loss of generality, assume that d = max{x, y} = x
>
> $\implies$ 10^d/n = (2^x)(5^x)/(2^x)(5^y) =  5^(x - y), which is an integer.
>
> $\implies$ In other words, $10^d \bmod n = 0$. For base 10, this gaurantees that 1/n is a
> terminating decimal.

I think, for a lot of people, no extra steps would be necessary. But I am writing this for people like me who need to understand every detail along the way.

Comment: To complete your argument, note that we can now write $\frac 1n=\frac m{10^d}$ and the right hand is obviously a terminating decimal (it's just $m$ preceded by some number of $0's$).

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I think that's a more obvious way then talking about mod.