# If $n$ is coprime to 10, then $1/n$ produces a repeating decimal.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms

**EDIT:** I have changed the title (twice). I am getting my terms and symbols jumbled up in my head. I hope that I have asked a clear question now.

Here are three statements that I believe to be true, but have only been able to prove them in one direction.

- **CASE 1:** Iff $n = 2^x5^y$ then $1/n$ produces a terminating decimal.
- **CASE 2:** Iff n is coprime to 10, 1/n produces a purely repeating decimal
- **CASE 3**: Iff $n = 2^x5^yn'$, where $n'$ is coprime to 10, then 1/n produces a repeating decimal after a non-repeating section.

I already [proved case 1 both ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3550362/362627), but I'm stuck on case 2. I think if I can prove case 2, then case 3 would be very easy.

**Question:**
Are the above statements true? If so, what are some hints to help me solve case 2?

**My work so far:**

Assume that $n$ is coprime to 10.

$\implies 10^k \bmod n = m$, where $m \in \{1, \dots, 9\}, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$

$\implies$ I'm really not sure where to go next...

*I should add that I never studied number theory before. This is for fun, on my own time, so simple explanations are better for me :)*

Comment: What do you mean by a repeating decimal? Is $0.333...=1/3$ repeating?

Comment: @Servaes yes, that is what I mean :)

Comment: But then what you ask to prove in the title is false.

Comment: @Servaes I forgot to add the \not in the title. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: The corrected title is precisely what you already proved in the linked question; if $n=2^x5^y$ then $1/n$ terminates. So if $1/n$ does not terminate then $n\neq2^x5^y$.

Comment: @Servaes Ok, so case 2 follows from case 1?

Comment: No, only one implication follows from case 1. This is the implication in your title. For the other implication; if $1/n$ is repeating with period $k>0$, then $10^k(1/n)-(1/n)$ is an integer, so $n$ divides $10^k-1$. In particular $n$ is coprime to $10$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all three statements are true.

**Terminating expansions:** A positive real number $x$ has a terminating decimal expansion iff there exists $k$ such that $10^k x \in \mathbb N$. Now suppose $x = 1/n$. Then 
$$\begin{align*}
&\exists k \in \mathbb N : 10^k \frac{1}n \in \mathbb N \\
\iff &\exists k, \ell \in \mathbb N : 10^k = n \ell
\end{align*}$$
That is, $1/n$ has a terminating decimal expansion iff it divides $10^k$ for some $k$. That is, iff its only prime divisors are $2$ and $5$. This proves the first claim.

**Periodic expansions.** A positive real number $x<1$ has a periodic decimal expansion iff there exists $k>0$ such that $10^k x - x \in \mathbb N$, i.e. $(10^k-1) x \in \mathbb N$. Now take $x = 1/n$, with $n > 1$. Then this is equivalent to saying that there exists $k>0$ such that $n$ divides $10^k - 1$. We want to show that this is equivalent to $10$ being coprime to $n$.

$n$ coprime to $10$ $\implies$ periodic expansion: Consider the numbers $10^0, 10^1, 10^2, \ldots$ and their remainders upon division by $n$. Because there are infinitely many numbers and only finitely many possible remainders, ...

> by the pigeonhole principle, there exist $p, q \in \mathbb N$ with $p < q$ and such that $10^p$ and $10^q$ have the same remainder upon division by $n$.

That is, ...

> $n$ divides $10^q - 10^p$.

We have $10^q - 10^p = 10^{p} (10^{q-p}-1)$.
Because $n$ divides this number, and $n$ is coprime to $10$, it must be that ...

> $n$ divides $10^{q-p} - 1$.

Thus $1/n$ has periodic expansion.

Periodic expansion $\implies$ $n$ coprime to $10$: By assumption, there exist $k, \ell \in \mathbb N$ with $10^k -1 = n \ell$, and $k \geq 1$. Suppose $n$ and $10$ are not coprime. Then there exists $d > 1$ that divides both $10$ and $n$. But then $d$ divides ...

> $$10^k - n \cdot \ell = 1\,,$$

... a contradiction with $d > 1$. Hence $n$ is coprime to $10$.

**Eventually periodic expansions.** The decimal expansion of any rational number is finite or eventually periodic, so it must be that the natural numbers $n$ not covered by the previous two cases are precisely those such that $1/n$ has an infinite, not immediately periodic decimal expansion.

Comment: Excellent! Now I have to learn about "the pigeonhole principle". Thanks for helping me expand my knowledge a little bit.

Comment: Ok, so why should the $d > 1$ factor that 10 and $n$ share necessarily divide $10^k -nl$? I am sure it is obvious, but I've been scratching around on paper for a bit and can't see it.

Comment: Got it, never mind.

Answer (score -1):

Counterexample to the title:

Prove that, in general if $1/n$ produces a repeating decimal, then $n = 2^x5^y$.

Let $n=7$.  $$\frac{1}{7} = 0.\overline{142857}$$

The number $7$ is prime, so $7 \ne 2^x 5^y$.

**UPDATE**

Hey, the title changed.  This actually was a valid response at the time!

Comment: Oh man! I'm sorry, that's a typo on my part! My dislexia kicked in. It should be $n \not = 2^x5^y$

Comment: First got a point for that!  Now at -1 !

Comment: @rocksNwaves, no problem.  Thanks!

Comment: I upvoted your answer! It's not your fault I asked a stupid question. That means two jerks downvoted you with no explanation. I hate that :(

Comment: Lol! ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I assume the argument for doing so is that the typo should have been obvious to you and answering the question as written is taking advantage.

Comment: 1). Seeing the title, didn't bother to read the question carefully ...

Comment: 2).  No problem about making a mistake.  Easy to type $=$ instead of $\ne$.

Comment: 3).  Interesting how people can "read into" an answer.  Again $\textbf{LoL!}$